# Ajax Json undefined object on success

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to use an API request from a widget I have installed but I have noticed that my Json data returns a "Object reference not set to instance of an object" exception on success.

Here is the Json:

```
{
  "ApiKey": "d4f37ba05a1941928de3109c8632b1ce", 
  "Text": "tesst%0A", 
  "Language": "en", 
  "Rule": "Preediting_Forum", 
  "Grammar": "1", 
  "Spell": "1", 
  "Style": "1", 
  "SessionMetadata": "Preediting_Forum;0", 
  "RequestFormat": "HTML"
}
```

Here is the ajax code for the post request:

```
$.ajax({
  url: settings.AcceptServerPath + "/Core/AcceptRequest",
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json",
  type: "POST",
  async: true,
  cache: true,
  data: jsonData,
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    handleRequestStatus(data, "ACCEPT");
  },
  complete: function (data) {},
  error: function (error) {
    displayFailedMessage("ACCEPT", configuration.language.errorRequestFailed);
  }
});
```

What could be the cause?

**Edit**
Here is the C# code:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AcceptRequest(CoreApiRequest requestObject)
        {
            try
            {
                if (requestObject == null || requestObject.Text.Length == 0)
                    requestObject = (CoreApiRequest)(new DataContractJsonSerializer(requestObject.GetType())).ReadObject(Request.InputStream);

                Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                if (requestObject.ApiKey != null && requestObject.ApiKey.Length > 0)
                {
                    parameters.Add("apiKey", requestObject.ApiKey);
                }
                else
                {
                    parameters.Add("username", requestObject.User);
                    parameters.Add("password", requestObject.Password);
                }

                string text = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(requestObject.Text, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);  

                parameters.Add("text", text);
                parameters.Add("languageid", requestObject.Language);
                parameters.Add("ruleset", requestObject.Rule);
                parameters.Add("grammar", requestObject.Grammar);
                parameters.Add("spell", requestObject.Spell);
                parameters.Add("style", requestObject.Style);

                parameters.Add("requestFormat", requestObject.RequestFormat);

                if (requestObject.GlobalSessionId != null && requestObject.GlobalSessionId.Length > 0)
                {
                    parameters.Add("globalSessionId", requestObject.GlobalSessionId);
                }

                if (requestObject.IEDomain != null && requestObject.IEDomain.Length > 0)
                    parameters.Add("ieDomain", requestObject.IEDomain);


                if (requestObject.SessionMetadata != null && requestObject.SessionMetadata.Length > 0)
                    parameters.Add("sessionMetadata", requestObject.SessionMetadata);

                var model = AcceptCoreManager.GenericRequest(parameters);
                return Json(model);


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var errorModel = new CoreApiException(e.Message, "Accept Request Controller");
                return Json(errorModel);
            }

        }
```

There is also a [RestHttpVerbFilter] for the AcceptRequest. Not sure which one is used in this case...

Comment: That comes from your C# code.  You need to debug it.

Comment: @SLaks I edit my post with the C# code. I'm not very familiar with it so how should I proceed to debug it in this case?

Comment: Learn how to use Visual Studio's debugger.  Also, delete your `catch` block so that the request will actually fail instead of silently returning useless JSON.

Answer (score 0):

i have the same issue, 
its because the response is 'no content',
when the response is 'no content', ie. nothing returned. ajax shows undefined object.
so make sure response contains json object. just try alert(JSON.stringify(data));

Comment: Has I said the data returns {"Exception":"Object reference not set to instance of an object","Context":"Accept Request Controller","ResponseStatus":"FAILED"...}. What I wanted to know is what causes this error even though the ajax request succeeded?